# intersphinx link creation issues for local files across multiple projects

Tags: python-sphinx

I have a few different Sphinx projects that I would like to refer to each other locally (no web server). I have separate code + build directories setup for the projects and was trying out `intersphinx` to solve this requirement.

My questions are:

1. Is there a better way of referring to two or more local projects within Sphinx?
2. Is there a way to strip out the second build in the path?

In my configuration file I have:

```py
intersphinx_mapping = {
    'doc1': ('../build/doc1',None)
}
```

so I get no issues in doing a make HTML, however when I look at the reference I've created with `:ref:'doc1 info <doc1:label1>'` I have in the HTML document:

`file:///<root path>/build/**build**/doc1/html/doc.html#label1`

So the issue is I get two "build" directory listings - it should of been:

`file:///<root path>/build/doc1/html/doc.html#label1.`

If I manually do this, it correctly pulls in the document.

I've also tried replacing `None` with `'../build/doc1'`.  If I drop the build from the mapping I do get an error in finding the `objects.inv` file for doc1.

I do not want to use absolute path since the end user getting this documentation may see it in another location and I want this to be cross platform...

My directory tree is essentially as follows:

```
Makefile
build/doc1/html
build/doc2/html
doc1
doc2
```

As a background, I'm trying this under Cygwin with Sphinx 1.7.5... I haven't tried Linux yet to see if I get the same behavior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a different path for your target and for your inventory.
Maybe you can try something like:

```py
intersphinx_mapping = {
    'doc1': ('../doc1', '../build/doc1/objects.inv')
}
```

If you want to keep the `None`, it is also possible to have both:

```py
intersphinx_mapping = {
    'doc1': ('../doc1', (None, '../build/doc1/objects.inv'))
}
```